# Create Instance variable in Laravel

Tags: php, instance-variables, laravel-5

I have a php class which having 4 methods.All the 4 methods are using some common variables, I've created those variables as instance variable. But i'm getting an error like "Undefined variable: " How can i solve this problem.
My code is,

```
public class test{
    public static $variable;

    public function func(){
      $variable = "Hello World";
      print_r($variable);
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to access them with `$this` if they are not static and if static use `self`. So in your case it would become `self::$variable`. I would suggest going through the manual for more info on OOP  in php

Answer (score 0):

Actually this code will not gives you any error as you just print the variable which you have defined exactly above print statement.

Demo : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cd43e866591ee0693cdcbeec6a230f583f756a67

If you want to assign value to `$variable` which is defined above the function then try this code :

```
<?php
class test {
    public static $variable;

    public function func(){
      self::$variable = "Hello World";
      print_r(self::$variable);
    }

}
$n = new test();
echo $n->func();
?>
```

Demo : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f11b726a678b9a5ee0e474d7ca194bb5ed75af22

Answer (score 0):

If you have same static value for that variable try this

```
class test 
{
    const variable ="Hello World";

      public function func()
      {
        echo self::variable;
      }
}

$name = new test;

$name->func();
```